# Java string (source code) to show in browser

Tags: java, url, networking, uri

I am programming a Java application that inspects the source code of a webpage an shows that webpage to me in my default browser when a condition in the source code is satisfied. 
I get my source code the following way:

> String source = getUrlSource(myURL);

To show a specific webpage I know I can use:

> java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(myURI);

But this is not enough for my application because of variable content, How can I get java to show me the webpage that is encoded in the string source?  I need the equivalent of something that would look like

`java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(sourceCodeString).`

**Update**: If the condition is not satisfied, it will reload the same page. So the complete program executes on 1 url. Java is probably not the right language for that purpose, maybe someone has a better language to do this behaviour>

Thanks for your help,

Comment: So `sourceCodeString` contains the HTML-Source of the page you want to show?

Comment: yes, in String format

Answer (score 2):

You can save the string in a file and open the file.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String html = "<html><body>Hello Browser</body></html>";
    File file = new File("test.html");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    writer.write(html);
    writer.close();

    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(file.toURI());
  }
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work more or less. Problem is that some images (or dynamic elements, no idea really) will not load. Java is probably the wrong language to do the stuff I want to do.

Comment: You can use absolute links an server for your resources. Example for absolute links: <img src="file:\C:\whatever\img.jpg">

Comment: @user2874101 You'll have the problem with the images in any case - no matter what programming language you're using. The image URLs inside your HTML are possibly relative, so they can't be resolved properly.

Comment: I understand but I cannot believe there isn't an easier solution.. Isn't there a function that will open a website in the browser and as return value give the source code.. that would do the trick..

Comment: In plain java i do not think so. But it could be that there is a library, but i do not know.